# Perform a HitTest on a Series MS Chart Control

Tags: c#, .net

How can i perform a HitTest on a Series in Ms Chart Control?? Because i couldn't find it anywhere. I want to make a line where until the line is crossing the Spline in MS Chart Control but the point is it not always a DataPoint.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456772.aspx
Under interactivity it explains how to use a hit test one mouse over.

Comment: yeah but i want to make a line where until the line is crossing the Spline in MS Chart Control but the point is it not always a DataPoint. Because i draw a line on a specific y Value and want to get the HitTest when the line is crossing the SPline